# How to access hidden field value in C# ? and I am setting the value of hidden field using jquery

Tags: jquery

am setting value of asp:hiddenfield using jquery. but when i access value of hiddenfield in .aspx.cs page , it show empty string.

**HTML**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLat"/>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLng" />
```

**JS**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        var address = $(".Hno").val() + " " + $(".Address").val() + "," + $(".City").val();  // Fetch Lattitude and logtittude for Using Google Map
        //alert(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
            //alert('LAT: ' + location.lat() + ' LANG: ' + location.lng());
            var Lat = $('#<% =hdnLat.ClientID %>').attr('value', location.lat());
            var lng = $('#<% =hdnLng.ClientID %>').attr('value', location.lng());
            //alert($('#<% =hdnLat.ClientID %>').val() + ","+$('#<% =hdnLng.ClientID %>').val());

        });
    }
</script
```

> here is my button where i am calling jquery function.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="Register2" OnClientClick="return codeAddress();"></asp:Button>
```

> I create btnUpdate_Click event when page is prerender.

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dlInvQueAnsV.ItemDataBound += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventHandler(this.dlInvQueAnsV_ItemDataBound);
        this.dlInvQueAnsE.ItemDataBound += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventHandler(this.dlInvQueAnsE_ItemDataBound);
        this.dgInvQue.ItemDataBound += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventHandler(this.dgInvQue_ItemDataBound);
        this.btnBack.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBack_Click);
        this.btnUpdate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnUpdate_Click);
        this.btnRegister.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRegister_Click);
        this.lbCloseAccount.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.lbCloseAccount_Click);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        this.ddlAdminComment.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ddlAdminComment_SelectedIndexChanged);
        this.btnSaveNote.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSaveNote_Click);
        this.btnSendCommentSMS.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSendCommentSMS_Click);
        this.btnSendCommentEmail.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSendCommentEmail_Click);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: here is mine html code       <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLat"/>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLng" />

Comment: how do you access the value of that field? please post your c# code. better if you provide all details at once...

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of a hidden field, don't use the `attr()` function but just use `val()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id$=hdnLat]').val(location.lat()); // Take the input where id ends with hdnLat
    $('input[id$=hdnLng]').val(location.lng()); // Take the input where id ends with hdnLng
});
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" Text="Maps" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

**C# code behind:**

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lat = this.hdnLat.Value;
    string lng = this.hdnLng.Value;
}
```

**JS function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {

        // other code

        return true;
    }
</script
```

Comment: okay .. and how can we acces the value of hiddenfield at c# side

Comment: i used this but it doesn't work . actually i need the values on button click

Comment: when i alert the value . it show correct value . But shows empty value at C# side

Comment: ok then there is a problem with your selector try my update above using `'input[id$=hdnLat]'` and `'input[id$=hdnLng]'`

Comment: Sir actually i am using asp hidden field control.

Comment: ok now I see it, you only have a client click event on your button not a server side. So in your code behind your click event is never called. Add `OnClick="btnUpdate"` to your button

Comment: sir the click event is created when page prerender

Comment: add this code at the end of your codeAddress method:  `__doPostBack('btnUpdate','')` or even better just add return true; at the end, view update above!

Answer (score 0):

To access value of hiddenfield on c# side, simply use

```
    string lat = Request.Form["hdnLat"];
    string lng = Request.Form["hdnLng"];
```